# What's the best place to save Sublime config file of projects?

Tags: sublimetext2

When I create a new project two files are generated:

- my_project.sublime-project
- my_project.sublime-workspace

Currently, I've about 8 project so these files are messep in one folder.
I don't know whether I should placed the *.sublime-project in my project folder (with git) or not.

I suppose that has a best way to do that to keep files organized :)

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on if you are sharing your repo with anyone else. For example, here's one of my project files:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
            {
                    "path": "corpus"
            }
    ]
}
```

Someone else may have that project checked out into a different directory than "corpus". But it gets more complicated with the workplace files, which get saved into the same directory. Those often have full paths to things that are very particular to your box.

So my recommendation is to put them somewhere outside your git repo, or to add them to your .gitignore file.

Comment: I'm not sharing my repo, Tt's a private project. In this case you suggest leave this file inside repo folder? And the other (sublime-workspace) in some folder of my computer?